# numpy 3d array -- flatten --> 1d array --> select one element in 1d --> how to know the index of the element in 3d?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, sampling

> numpy 3d array -- flatten --> 1d array --> select one element in 1d
> array
> --> how to know the index of the element in 3d? (?, ?, ?)

For example,

I have 3d histogram data in 3d-array `D`.
Let `D` be `D = np.random.randint(0,100, size=(4,3,2))`.

and then the probability of each element would be equal to `P = D / D.sum(0).sum(0).sum(0)`.

Let P be flattened like `P_flat = P.reshape(-1)`.

and then randomly chose n-sample from `P_flat`: `samples = np.random.choice(len(P_flat), n, p=P_flat)`

and then, I hope to convert 1D index (=`samples`) to 3D index of `D`.

For example, convert(`samples = [3, 2, 5]`)  -> `[[?,?,?], [?,?,?], [?,?,?]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.unravel_index` ([doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html)) for that:

```
indices = np.array(np.unravel_index(samples, D.shape)).T
```